# Handlebars if statement issue

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

```
     {{#each this.data.roles as |role|}}
          {{#if (eq role.name ( 'moderator' 'organizer'))}}
            <div class="item">
              {{role.name}}
            </div>
          {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
```

It is only giving div with moderator only not with organizer

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your helper invocation needs a slight tweak. I assume you need to show the `div` for both moderator and organizer role. So, the condition (in js) should be like,

`role === "moderator" || role === "organizer"`

the same can be translated into the handlebar expressions with the help of `eq` and `or` helpers like:

```
{{#each this.data.roles as |role|}}
  {{#if (or (eq role.name "moderator") (eq role.name "organizer"))}}
    <div class="item">
      {{role.name}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```